# How to improve memory management for matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, memory-management, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to learn about matrix multiplication and encounter this code for Strassen multiplication vs standard matrix multiplication, so I've tried to implement it. However, this code uses too much memory to the point that when the matrix it's big enough it kills the program. Also, because it uses too much memory it takes longer to process.

I'm not too comfortable to mess around with the code too much since I don't fully understand complex memory management and I would really like to learn about this topic.

Build in the code there's a cut parameter and found that at 320 makes it run faster and seems like improves with memory management.

**EDIT.** I've implemented a copy constructor, destructor and a function to track memory usage and it fixed the memory leaks it was having, but the big jump on the time between 1990 dimension to 2100 still there for the Strassen matrix.

matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H

#define MATRIX_H



#include <vector>

using namespace std;



class matrix

{

public:

    matrix(int dim, bool random, bool strassen);

    matrix(const matrix& old_m);



    inline int dim() {

        return dim_;

    }

    inline int& operator()(unsigned row, unsigned col) {

        return data_[dim_ * row + col];

    }



    inline int operator()(unsigned row, unsigned col) const {

        return data_[dim_ * row + col];

    }



    void print();

    matrix operator+(matrix b);

    matrix operator-(matrix b);

    ~matrix();



private:

    int dim_;

    int* data_;

};



#endif
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

#include "SAMmatrix.h"

using namespace std;



matrix::matrix(int dim, bool random, bool strassen) : dim_(dim) {

    if (strassen) {

        int dim2 = 2;

        while (dim2 < dim)

            dim2 *= 2;

        dim_ = dim2;

    }



    data_ = new int[dim_ * dim_];

    if (!random) return;



    for (int i = 0; i < dim_ * dim_; i++)

        data_[i] = rand() % 10;

}

matrix::matrix(const matrix& old_m){

    dim_ = old_m.dim_;  

    data_ = new int[dim_ * dim_];

    for (int i = 0; i < dim_ * dim_; i++)

        data_[i] = old_m.data_[i]; 

}



void matrix::print() {

    for (int i = 0; i < dim_; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < dim_; j++)

            cout << (*this)(i, j) << " ";

        cout << "\n";

    }

    cout << "\n";

}



matrix matrix::operator+(matrix b) {

    matrix c(dim_, false, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim_; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < dim_; j++)

            c(i, j) = (*this)(i, j) + b(i, j);



    return c;

}



matrix matrix::operator-(matrix b) {

    matrix c(dim_, false, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim_; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < dim_; j++)

            c(i, j) = (*this)(i, j) - b(i, j);



    return c;

}

matrix::~matrix()

{

    delete [] data_;

}
```

Matrix main

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

#include <sys/time.h>

#include "SAMmatrix.h"

#include "stdlib.h"

#include "stdio.h"

#include "string.h"





typedef pair<matrix, long> result;



int cut = 64;



matrix mult_std(matrix a, matrix b) 

{

    matrix c(a.dim(), false, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.dim(); i++)

        for (int k = 0; k < a.dim(); k++)

            for (int j = 0; j < a.dim(); j++)

                c(i, j) += a(i, k) * b(k, j);



    return c;

}



matrix get_part(int pi, int pj, matrix m) 

{

    matrix p(m.dim() / 2, false, true);

    pi = pi * p.dim();

    pj = pj * p.dim();



    for (int i = 0; i < p.dim(); i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < p.dim(); j++)

            p(i, j) = m(i + pi, j + pj);



    return p;

}



void set_part(int pi, int pj, matrix* m, matrix p) 

{

    pi = pi * p.dim();

    pj = pj * p.dim();



    for (int i = 0; i < p.dim(); i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < p.dim(); j++)

            (*m)(i + pi, j + pj) = p(i, j);

}



matrix mult_strassen(matrix a, matrix b) 

{

    if (a.dim() <= cut)

        return mult_std(a, b);



    matrix a11 = get_part(0, 0, a);

    matrix a12 = get_part(0, 1, a);

    matrix a21 = get_part(1, 0, a);

    matrix a22 = get_part(1, 1, a);



    matrix b11 = get_part(0, 0, b);

    matrix b12 = get_part(0, 1, b);

    matrix b21 = get_part(1, 0, b);

    matrix b22 = get_part(1, 1, b);



    matrix m1 = mult_strassen(a11 + a22, b11 + b22);

    matrix m2 = mult_strassen(a21 + a22, b11);

    matrix m3 = mult_strassen(a11, b12 - b22);

    matrix m4 = mult_strassen(a22, b21 - b11);

    matrix m5 = mult_strassen(a11 + a12, b22);

    matrix m6 = mult_strassen(a21 - a11, b11 + b12);

    matrix m7 = mult_strassen(a12 - a22, b21 + b22);



    matrix c(a.dim(), false, true);

    set_part(0, 0, &c, m1 + m4 - m5 + m7);

    set_part(0, 1, &c, m3 + m5);

    set_part(1, 0, &c, m2 + m4);

    set_part(1, 1, &c, m1 - m2 + m3 + m6);



    return c;

}



pair<matrix, long> run(matrix(*f)(matrix, matrix), matrix a, matrix b) 

{

    struct timeval start, end;



    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    matrix c = f(a, b);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    long e = (end.tv_sec * 1000 + end.tv_usec / 1000);

    long s = (start.tv_sec * 1000 + start.tv_usec / 1000);



    return pair<matrix, long>(c, e - s);

}



int parseLine(char* line){ /* overflow*/

    // This assumes that a digit will be found and the line ends in " Kb".

    int i = strlen(line);

    const char* p = line;

    while (*p <'0' || *p > '9') p++;

    line[i-3] = '\0';

    i = atoi(p);

    return i;

}



int getValue(){ //Note: this value is in KB!

    FILE* file = fopen("/proc/self/status", "r");

    int result = -1;

    char line[128];



    while (fgets(line, 128, file) != NULL){

        if (strncmp(line, "VmSize:", 7) == 0){

            result = parseLine(line);

            break;

        }

    }

    fclose(file);

    return result;

}



int main() 

{

    /* test cut of for strassen

    /*

    for (cut = 2; cut <= 512; cut++) {

            matrix a(512, true, true);

            matrix b(512, true, true);

            result r = run(mult_strassen, a, b);

            cout << cut << " " << r.second << "\n";

    }

    */



    /* performance test: standard and strassen */

    /*1024 going up by 64*/

    for (int dim = 1500; dim <= 2300; dim += 200) 

    {

        double space = getValue() * .01;

        cout << "Space before: " << space << "Mb" << "\n";

        matrix a(dim, true, false);

        matrix b(dim, true, false);

        result std = run(mult_std, a, b);

        matrix c(dim, true, true);

        matrix d(dim, true, true);

        result strassen = run(mult_strassen, c, d);

        cout << "Dim " << "   Std  " << " Stranssen" << endl;

        cout << dim << " " << std.second << "ms " << strassen.second << "ms " << "\n";

        double spaceA = getValue() * .01;

        cout << "Space: " << spaceA << "Mb" << "\n";

        cout << " " << endl;
    }

}
```

I set it to go from 1500 to 2300 by 200 and the program is "killed" before finishing

```
1500 2406 4250 
1700 3463 4252 
1900 4819 4247 
2100 6487 30023 
Killed
```

Also, it shouldn't make a big jump on time like that when the dimension goes from 1900 to 2100.

Comment: Code needs to be included in the question.  Links to code are not acceptable, because they can break and become inaccessible.  See [ask].

Comment: I took a look at your code.  There is no need to go further, since you failed to implement the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Thus `operator +` is broken (plus any part of the code where you are copying `matrix` objects) and your issues probably have nothing to do with matrix size.  So as soon as you post the code here, get ready for a "duplicate of" closure to your question.